# Can't open executable (missing dll files)

Tags: visual-studio, github

When i build the exe file from visual studio, i see the following message:

[image]

The project is on ([project](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/Playlists))

Answer (score 0):

> When i build the exe file from visual studio, i see the following message:
>
> [image]

There is a good chance you have not installed a required component.  This assumption is based, on a Visual Studio feedback response from Microsoft, from a user who indicated they had the same problem.

> User's Question: **built for each combination of Debug / Release x32 / x64
>   vcruntime140_app.dll and so on missing, the program doesnt start when starting from Explorer**
>
> Microsoft: **In order to investigate this issue more accurately, please first confirm if you have installed “Visual C++ runtime for UWP” in Individual components.**
>
> [image]
>
> But I can't find the individual component in the red box.

This is due to the fact you are using Visual Studio 2019 and the feature was moved to the Windows SDK installation.

[image]